# Limit comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent, so $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0.$

Consider $$\lim_{n\to\infty} {\left(\dfrac{{a_n}^{1/2}}{n}\right)\over{\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)}} $$
which is equivalent to $\lim_{n\to\infty} n{a_n}^{1/2}$

The above are my steps for solving the question. In the question it is given that infinite series  $ \sum a_n$ is convergent, now I am trying to use limit comparison test to conclude the infinite series of $$\frac{{a_n}^{1/2}}{n}$$ is convergent. But I am not sure how to evaluate this limit : $\lim_{n\to\infty} n{a_n}^{1/2}$.
Or anyone has other method to show that the infinite series $$\sum \frac{{a_n}^{1/2}}{n}$$ is convergent given the infinite series $\sum a_n$ is convergent?

Comment: @Nilan is (1/n)^2

Comment: I fixed it. Is it correct?

Comment: I think Dirichlet test will work for your question.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. In fact $$\left(\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{a_{n}^{1/2}}{n}\right)^{2}=\left(\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n\leq N}\frac{a_{n}^{1/2}}{n}\right)^{2}=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{n\leq N}\frac{a_{n}^{1/2}}{n}\right)^{2}\leq\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n\leq N}a_{n}\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n\leq N}\frac{1}{n^{2}}<\infty.
 $$